# How to use if="some condition" in ZK template tag

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, zk

I have a <template> tag in my ZUL file, and I want to use this template when some condition accured (for example, when some LABEL's value change to some text).

Please look at below code... As you can see, "templateStatus" is my label's name, but it did not work.

How can I fix this issue?

```
    <template name="allTaskTemplate" var="allTask" if="templateStatus.value == 'allTask'">
        <row>
            <label value="" />
            <label value="@load(allTask.documentDTO.docTypeDTO.title)"/>
            <label value="@load(allTask.documentDTO.docNumber)"/>
            <label value="@load(allTask.documentDTO.docDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@load(allTask.assignerID)"/>
            <label value="@load(allTask.assigneeID)"/>
            <label value="@load(allTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@load(allTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@load(allTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@load(allTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@load(allTask.documentDTO.docTypeStateDTO.stateActionDTO.actionDTO.title)"/>
            <label value="@load(allTask.catalogDTO.catalogTypeDTO.title)"/>
        </row>
    </template>
</grid>
```

Answer (score 6):

Using an `if` statement:

```
<zk if="${vm.type=='foo'}">
    <!-- Child components -->
</zk>

<zk if="${vm.type=='check'}">
    <!-- Child components -->
</zk>

<zk if="${vm.type=='something'}">
    <!-- Child components -->
</zk>

<zk if="${vm.type=='value'}">
    <!-- Child components -->
</zk>
```

Answer (score 2):

See the below example of ZK. You can use conditional templates...

```
<grid model="@bind(vm.itemList) @template(vm.type eq 'foo'?'template1':'template2')">
    <template name="template1">
    <!-- child components -->
    </template>

    <template name="template2">
    <!-- child components -->
    </template>
</grid>
```

For more information, you can see the official page of ZK, *[Collection and Selection](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Data_Binding/Collection_and_Selection)*.

Se the below code for...

```
   <menubar id="mbar" children="@bind(vm.menuList) @template(empty each.children?'menuitem':'menu')">
    <template name="menu" var="menu">
        <menu label="@bind(menu.name)">
            <menupopup children="@bind(menu.children) @template(empty each.children?'menuitem':'menu')"/>
        </menu>
    </template>
    <template name="menuitem" var="item">
        <menuitem label="@bind(item.name)" onClick="@command('menuClicked',node=item)" />
    </template>
</menubar>
```

See the above. Using more than two templates you can do something like this. I don't know your requirement, but you can use the above logic and implement it in your code.

Or you can see the ZK Forum for the same, [Zk forum](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/85540/different-template-for-each-grid-row/).

Comment: thanks dear subodh , but i have 4 template . do you have any suggestion for my situation?