# zk element if @load equals condition

Tags: zk, zul

I have a list which I build in zul file.

```
<listbox id="someId" model="@load(vm.searchResults)" selectedItem="@bind(vm.selectedItem)" vflex="1" multiple="true">
    <listhead>
        <listheader label="${labels.l1}" width="150px" align="center"/>
        <listheader label="${labels.l2}" width="150px" align="center"/>
        <listheader label="${labels.l3}" width="100px" align="center"/>
    <listheader label="${labels.l4}" width="400px" align="center"/>
    </listhead>
    <template name="model">
        <listitem style="text-align: left;">
            <listcell style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: left;">
                <label value="@load(each.l1)"/>
            </listcell>
            <listcell style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: left;">
                <label value="@load(each.l2)"/>
            </listcell>
            <listcell style="word-wrap: break-word; text-align: left;">
                <label value="@load(each.l3)"/>
                <a action="" label="should be displayed when some param is equals to 3 " if="{each.someParam=='3'}"/>
            </listcell>
            <listcell style="text-align: left;">
                <label value="@load(each.l4)"/>
            </listcell>
        </listitem>
    </template>
</listbox>
```

I need to display **a** element when each some param is 3. How do I get it?

```
<a action="" label="should be displayed when some param is equals to 3 " if="{each.someParam=='3'}"/>
```

I checked this 
[How to use if="some condition" in ZK template tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332500/how-to-use-if-some-condition-in-zk-template-tag)

But it did not help me.

I also tried

```
<a action="" label="should be displayed when some param is equals to 3 " if="{@(each.someParam)=='3'}"/>
```

Did not work either. **'3'** or **3** does not change anything. If I remove **if** condition **a** element is displayed. But I want to display it only when it meets if condition.

Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice that you solved your problem.
I'll make this answer so you can have more understanding why it didn't work.

First of all, the `if` attribute can't handle dynamic data.
So only decleration with ${...} (static) can work.
With ZK 8, there is a new tag, `<if test="">`, and this can handle dynamic data.

It's not the problem that you need to set the if in a `<zk>` tag but the problem in your example is the `@` or the missing `$`.
This may be said, the `@{...}` is deprecated databinding.
It's the evolution to MVVM pattern **but** it was so crapy that they deprecated it and also removed most of the documentation about this, witch is a good case so nobody new can learn to use this.

Maybe a suggestion of what could help you :

```
<style>
    .makeYourName {
        word-wrap: break-word; 
        text-align: left;
     }
</style>
```

and then create your listcell like :

```
<listcell sclass="makeYourName">
```

could save you time when you need to refactor your styling.

Comment: Thanks, I absolutely agree about styling. This code was not created by me.

Comment: And we use different zk versions: 6, 7, 8.

Comment: I'm active at code review so it's a kind of (maybe bad) habbit to suggest improvements. This doesn't mean that the code is wrong or badly written.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in similar project.

```
<zk if="${(each.l3== 3)}">
    <a action="" label="should be displayed when some param is equals to 3"/>
</zk>
```

That works for me.

Pay attention
if="${each.l3== 3}"